# array and string manipulation

Tags: arrays, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two arrays: (arrayA contains ints and arrayB and arrayC contain strings)

```
arrayA = [5, 4]
arrayB = ["id_1", "id_2"] #arrayA and arrayB always have same lengths 
arrayC = ['3', '4', '15', '20', '23', '8', '11', '14', '21']
```

I want result:

```
res = {"id_1": ['3', '4', '15', '20', '23'], 
       "id_2": ['8', '11', '14', '21']}
```

so basically I want to tell the program that id_1 of arrayB contains first 5 strings and id_2 of arrayB contains next 4 strings.

similarly a result from a problem like following would be:

```
A = [2, 1, 3, 4]
B = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
C = ['23', '8', '11', '3', '4', '15', '20', '23', '100', '45'] 

res = {"a": ['23', '8'], 
       "b": ['11'],
       "c": ['3', '4', '15'], 
       "d": ['20', '23', '100', '45']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
A = [2, 1, 3, 4]
B = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
C = ['23', '8', '11', '3', '4', '15', '20', '23', '100', '45'] 


res = {}
ix = 0
for k, l in zip(B, A):
    res[k] = C[ix:(ix+l)]
    ix += l

print(res)

# {'a': ['23', '8'], 'b': ['11'], 'c': ['3', '4', '15'], 'd': ['20', '23', '100', '45']}
```

The solution works as follows:

First, we create a dictionary called `res` to keep track of the result. Then, we make a variable called `ix` and set it to 0. This variable helps us keep track of where to index the array `C` to get the desired values for our result dictionary. Further, we `zip` arrays `B` and `A`. This zipping process is equivalent to creating a new list of tuples from `B` and `A` that looks like `[("a", 2), ("b", 1), ("c", 3), ("d", 4)]`. Now that you have this zipped container, we iterate through with a `for-loop`; and hence the `for k, l in zip(B, A)` part. Subsequently, at every iteration, we slice array `C` from `ix` to `ix + l`; where `l` is the corresponding integer value from array `A`. The values from this slicing operation are saved in our `res` dictionary with a key from the array `B`. Finally, we increment the value `ix` by the value of `l`, to make sure that the next slice we make moves forward through array `C`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for this. can you please explain the code too? what is happening in for loop and what is zip function?

Comment: this was so beautifully and thoroughly explained! thank you so much! I have never worked witn for loop containing more than one variables but now i have and it has made life so much more easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to peel off portions of `C` according to the lengths provided by `A`. For this to work, you'll also need to make `C` an iterator so the slices start where the last slice left off:

```
import itertools as IT
A = [2, 1, 3, 4]
B = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
C = ['23', '8', '11', '3', '4', '15', '20', '23', '100', '45'] 
C = iter(C)
result = {bi: list(IT.islice(C, ai)) for ai, bi in zip(A, B)}
print(result)
```

yields

```
{'b': ['11'], 
 'c': ['3', '4', '15'], 
 'd': ['20', '23', '100', '45'], 
 'a': ['23', '8']}
```

Comment: thank you so much but i have never used itertools before. can you please explain each line of the code?

Comment: Your question is too broad since I don't know how much you already know. If everything about the line is a complete mystery, then the place to start is by reading the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), in particular, [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), and `islice`. If  you have a more specific question, I'd be glad to explain.

Comment: thank you so much for providing the references! I will definitely look them up and ask you if I have further questions!

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [2, 1, 3, 4]
B = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
C = ['23', '8', '11', '3', '4', '15', '20', '23', '100', '45']
res = {}
ind = 0
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    res[B[i]] = C[ind:A[i] + ind]
    ind = ind + A[i]

print(res)
```

result:

```
{'a': ['23', '8'], 'b': ['11'], 'c': ['3', '4', '15'], 'd': ['20', '23', '100', '45']}
```